# Printing column/variable names after feature selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-selection

I am trying feature selection on the [Iris dateset](https://gist.github.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7#file-iris-csv).

I'm referencing from [Feature Selection with Univariate Statistical Tests](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-machine-learning-python/)

I am using below lines and I want to find out the significant features:

```
import pandas
from pandas import read_csv
from numpy import set_printoptions
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif

dataframe = pandas.read_csv("C:\\dateset\\iris.csv"]))
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:4]
Y = array[:,4]

test = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k=2)
fit = test.fit(X, Y)

set_printoptions(precision=2)
arr = fit.scores_

print (arr)

# [ 119.26   47.36 1179.03  959.32]
```

To show the indexes of the top 2 by its score, I added:

```
idx = (-arr).argsort()[:2]
print (idx)

# [2 3]
```

Further, how can I have the column/variable names (instead of their indexes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use indexing, here is possible use columns names, because selected first 4 columns:

```
#first 4 columns
X = array[:,0:4]

cols = dataframe.columns[idx]
```

If selection is different for `X` variable is necessary also filter by position DataFrame:

```
#e.g. selected 3. to 7. column
X = array[:,2:6]

cols = dataframe.iloc[:, 2:6].columns[idx]
```

Comment: superb, sir! thank you and glad to have your guidance again!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
from pandas import read_csv
from numpy import set_printoptions
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif

dataframe = pandas.read_csv("iris.csv")
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:4]
Y = array[:,4]

test = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k=2)
fit = test.fit(X, Y)

set_printoptions(precision=2)
arr = fit.scores_

idx = (-arr).argsort()[:2]
print (idx)

print (arr)
#names=[dataframe.columns[j] for j in X]

names = dataframe.columns[idx]
print(names)
```

Output

```
[2 3]
[ 119.26   47.36 1179.03  959.32]
Index(['petal_length', 'petal_width'], dtype='object')
```